# Is there a sales term for how "hot" or "strong" a prospect a customer is?

Tags: single-word-requests, terminology

I'm pretty sure my grammar is off in that title, because I'm awkwardly writing around a missing word.

If a salesperson has time to call one of two customers, he or she will want to reach out to the one which, based on all the information available, is more likely to be interested in making a purchase.  You could say "the stronger prospect".  Is there a single-word adjective or simple phrase to represent a measure of this "likelihood-to-buy" quality in a prospect?  "[Prospect] strength", "quality", and "score" come to mind, but they're vague, I'm hoping for something more specific to the world of sales.  I'm not familiar with their jargon, I just learned what a "spiff" is the other day.

"Interest" is close, but the context is one of data mining based on factors other than the customers' expressed interest, so I think that would be a little deceptive.

For context, this will be a field in a customer relationship management app.

Comment: I've heard the word "banker" used in sales to describe a prospect with a high conversion probability, but that's not an adjective.  Ideally you want something that could work on a percentage scale.  Why don't you invent the term "Convertaprobability"?

Comment: What about *easier*, as in *easier mark*, or *fatter*, as in *fatter pigeon*?

Comment: @jwpat7: "Easier" is good, but as a noun it would be "Ease", which is another rather vague word.  The others imply a less-than-respectful attitude toward our customers!

Answer (score 5):

I would call them the more *promising* prospect.

Comment: Hmm, as a noun, I'd have "Promise", which can be misinterpreted.

Answer (score 4):

The *firmness* of the prospect is one way to refer to what you're describing. The firmer a prospect, the more likely he or she is to buy your product.

You are also gauging the *probability* of a sale. So something like *Sales Probability* might work as your field name.

Comment: I like "Probability", it's a little more specific than "Quality" or "Firmness".

Answer (score 3):

The usual term for the process of making the determination of this property is *lead qualification*, which is much more frequently written of than the property it determines, which is *quality*.  It's probably the vagueness you note in the concept of "quality" which leads people to speak of the process more often than the result.